# Installing SSD without bracket

Tags: installation, ssd

I just got my brand new SSD. I thought that I will receive bracket to mount it in 3.5 socket but there is no such thing in the box. 
Can I just place it on top of my HD using something to separate them from each other?

Comment: [This](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/how-to-install-ssd-without-a-mounting-bracket.156965/) could help you.

Comment: Sure, if you don't mind all the heat from the HDD going up through the SSD (bad idea). :) Really, mount it however you'd like and take your chances.  If you're actually worried about it, then you're best off going and [getting a bracket](http://www.startech.com/HDD/Brackets/25in-Hard-Drive-to-35in-Drive-Bay-Mounting-Kit~BRACKET25SAT).

Comment: just don't block any ventilation holes on the hdd.

Comment: Thanks for all repplies. I read a little and just dropped it inside computer. It works perfectly fine. Meanwhile I will get a bracket ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While is is technically possible to simply lay the drive on top of another drive, it is not best to do so.

Heat is always an issue, as it any movement or vibration, which may cause the SSD to eventually slide off of the drive it is setting on top of.

Brackets are not generally included in an SSD package, as many times there is no need for them. This keeps the cost down, though there are sometimes package deals that include the bracket.

Considering how inexpensive brackets are, it is really best to simply buy one and install the drive in the correct and safest manner.

Comment: This is exacly what I am going to do.